# Format the json encode just like on laravel php

Tags: php, arrays

Supposed I have a query that gets the image from a certain tweet

```
[
     {
         "pic": "/upload/15680712995mb.jpg",
        "tweet_id": "48"
     },
     {
         "pic": "/upload/1568071299test.PNG",
         "tweet_id": "48"
     },
     {
         "pic": "/upload/1568015310test.PNG",
         "tweet_id": "47"
     } 
]
```

And I have a result also from a query that gets all of the tweet

```
[
    {
        "id": "48",
        "tweet": "test",
    },
    {
        "id": "47",
        "tweet": "test tweet",
    },

    {
        "id": "45",
        "tweet": "test tweet 3",
    }
]
```

How can I format the result like this (Just like on laravel)

```
[
    {
        "id": "48",
        "tweet": "test",
        "pics": [
            [
                "/upload/15680712995mb.jpg"
            ],
            [
               "/upload/1568071299test.PNG"
            ],
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "47",
        "tweet": "test tweet",
        "pics" : [
            [
                 "/upload/1568015310test.PNG"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "45",
        "tweet": "test tweet 3",
        "pics" : []
    }
]
```

And this is my simplified code

```
public function getTweets()
{
    $pics =  $this->model->getPics();

    $aTweets =  $this->model->getTweets();
    $map = [];
    $props = [];
    foreach ($aTweets as $sTweet) {
        $map['id'] =  $sTweet['id'];
        $map['tweet'] =  $sTweet['tweet'];

        foreach ($pics as $pic) {
            if ($pic['id'] === $sTweet['tweet_id']) {
                $map['pics'] = [$pic['pic']];
            }
        }

        $props[] = $map;

    }
    return $props;
}
```

but it just gives me the following output

```
{
    "id": "48",
    "tweet": "test",
    "pics": [
        "/upload/1568015310test.PNG"
    ]
},
{
    "id": "47",
    "tweet": "test tweet",
    "pics": [
        "/upload/1568015310test.PNG"
    ]
},
```

Any idea how can I format the result. thanks in advance.?

Comment: just add another nesting, and continually push `$map['pics'][] = whatever value you need here`

Comment: i dont understand why im getting an abnormal result if the tweet _id = id that is when pics array should be push. right now im getting all the result even if the tweet_id is not equal to id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what's troubling you but in order to add multiple values inside, just put another nesting like what I've eluded in the comments section:

```
$map['pics'][] = $pic['pic'];
        //   ^
```

So to complete the answer:

```
$map = [];
$props = [];
foreach ($aTweets as $sTweet) {
    $map['id'] =  $sTweet['id'];
    $map['tweet'] =  $sTweet['tweet'];
    $map['pics'] = []; // initialize
    foreach ($pics as $pic) {
        if ($pic['tweet_id'] === $sTweet['id']) {
            $map['pics'][] = [$pic['pic']];
        }
    }

    $props[] = $map;
}
```

This essentially creates another dimension for `pics` index as an array and continually pushing, provided they have the same ID.

Sidenote: `tweet_id` is to *pics* and `id` is to *aTweets*. Your's have the other way around.

Comment: sir it should empty again the arrays because the result is appending with the previous result

Comment: He needs `$map['pics'][] = [$pic['pic']];`

Comment: it is still appending

Comment: @Beginner add the initialization before the second foreach to reset the values, just like what i added above, i'm not sure why you need another nesting in each `pic` like `[$pic['pic']]`, but if it requires you to do it, just simply add it in